# Unable to connect to remote SS analysis services

Tags: c#, sql, ssas

I'm trying to connect to analysis services by C# .net, from my desktop computer, to a server that includes that service.I used 'Server' class in C# to make the connection but i got the following error

> "Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

, then I try to ran my program inside the server locally and i saw that it ran successfully.I considered all authentication parameters in my connection string in both tests.I tried another test ,to see if the problem was from my computer, I ran my program in  another computer which had the same username and password like my server and i see it worked successfully too.

This is my code

```
Server server = new Server();
server.Connect("Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Data Source=192.168.30.212;User ID = administrator;Password =XXXXXXX;Initial Catalog = Cubeee;");
```

do you think that this a security bug from microsoft ?!

Comment: _"do you think that this a security bug from microsoft ?!"_ - doubtful.  _"[The First Rule of Programming: It's Always Your Fault](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/)"_

Comment: Are you able to ping the Data Source IP from the computer where you're getting the connection error?

Comment: Please see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33671651/5070440

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connecting to Analysis Service from ASP.net application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33668819/connecting-to-analysis-service-from-asp-net-application)

Comment: Thanks to you GregGalloway, my problem solved !